# Classic ASP update on button click working only in IE not in other browsers

Tags: javascript, html, dom, asp-classic, adodb

I am working on Classic ASP application ,I have html table populated from sql database,  the html table has checkboxes in one of the cells,  on check box click I am opening a popup window where I am doing some update and after submitting, window gets closed automatically and previous page gets refreshed with the updated value ( here checkbox gets replaced with the updated value).
Working fine with IE but not updating with other browers.

For testing pop up window , I commented javascript window close and found that for IE data updates in the database but in other browsers it does nothing. May be issue with ADODB settings.The data I am updating is the current date and once it gets stored in the database , the previous page gets current date instead of checkbox.

Please help , I am new to classic asp.
**Update:** I printed the query , on IE it is printing correctly but in Chrome it is printing second parameter with some blank space on right. Example:in IE 'SHP' but in Chrome 'SHP '

```
 <!-- language: lang-js -->

        function CloseWindow() 
        {
                var trackerreport = document.getElementById("trackerreport").innerText;
                var reporttype = document.getElementById("reporttype").innerText;
                var report = reporttype.trim();
                document.getElementById("Hidden1").value = trackerreport;
                document.getElementById("Hidden2").value = reporttype;      

             switch (report) 
             {
            case "SHP": 
                 document.frmDtls.hfrom.value = 'DelSHP' ;
                 break;
            case "WHS":
                document.frmDtls.hfrom.value = 'DelWHS' ;
                break;
            default:
                alert("None");
                break;
            }     
               document.frmDtls.method = "post" ;
               document.frmDtls.action = "PRDB_UPDATE_BATCH_ORDER_PROCESSING_TRACKER_REPORT_SEGMENT_TIMESTAMP.asp" ;
               document.frmDtls.submit();
               window.close();
               window.opener.location.reload();
        }



    <!-- language: lang-vb -->
        <div align="center">
        <p align="center">
        <input type="button" style="background:yellow;color:black;height:25px; width:100px" value="Confirm" onclick="javascript: return CloseWindow();"> 
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <!--<input type="submit" style="background:yellow;color:black;height:25px; width:100px" value="Confirm" >  -->
        <input type="button" style="background:yellow;color:black;height:25px; width:100px" value="Cancel" onclick="javascript: return CancelWindow();">
        </p>
        </div>



        <%

            Set objCommand = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")  
            Set objRec = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Recordset")
            objCommand.ActiveConnection = strConnect

            Dim sConn
            Dim tracker
            Dim reporttype
            Dim trackernew

         If Request("hfrom") = "DelSHP" Then

                Set sConn = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Connection")
                sConn.Open strConnect

                tracker = Trim(Request("Hidden1"))
                trackernew = CInt(tracker)
                reporttype = Trim(Request("Hidden2"))
                username = Trim(Request("Hidden3"))
                objCommand.CommandText = "EXEC usp_UPDATE_BATCH_ORDER_PROCESSING_TRACKER_REPORT_SEGMENT '"&trackernew&"','"&reporttype&"','"&username&"'; "
                Set objRecord = objCommand.Execute
                sConn.Close
                Set objRecord = Nothing
                Set sConn = Nothing

        End If

        If Request("hfrom") = "DelWHS" Then

                Set sConn = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Connection")
                sConn.Open strConnect

                tracker = Trim(Request("Hidden1"))
                trackernew = CInt(tracker)
                reporttype = Trim(Request("Hidden2"))
                username = Trim(Request("Hidden3"))
                objCommand.CommandText = "EXEC usp_UPDATE_BATCH_ORDER_PROCESSING_TRACKER_REPORT_SEGMENT '"&trackernew&"','"&reporttype&"','"&username&"'; "
                Set objRecord = objCommand.Execute
                sConn.Close
                Set objRecord = Nothing
                Set sConn = Nothing

        End If
        %>

    <!-- language: lang-html -->

        <div align="center"><center>
        <form id="frmDtls" name="frmDtls">
        <input type="hidden" name="hfrom" value = "">
        <input id="Hidden1" name="Hidden1" type="hidden" runat="server" />
        <input id="Hidden2" name="Hidden2" type="hidden" runat="server" />
        <input id="Hidden3" name="Hidden3" type="hidden" runat="server" value="<%= l_username%>" />

        <table border="2" width="50%">
         <tr>
            <td width="40%" align="center" bgcolor="#C0C0C0"><strong><font size="2">Tracker Report ID </font><small>:</small></strong></td>
            <td id="trackerreport" width="60%" align="center" bgcolor="#C0C0C0"><strong><%=L_trackerreportid %></strong>&nbsp;</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td width="40%" align="center" bgcolor="#C0C0C0"><strong><font size="2">Segment Status Event </font><small>:</small></strong></td>
            <td id="reporttype" width="60%" align="center" bgcolor="#C0C0C0"><strong><%=L_reporttype %></strong>&nbsp;</td>
         </tr>

        </table>
        </center></div>
```

Comment: You're missing a closing `</form>` in your HTML, which could be preventing the form from posting correctly in other browsers.

Comment: Added closing tag as well , still no luck

Comment: Hey , I printed the query and Chrome is printing parameter reporttype with some space on the right

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue , for some reasons javascript was skipping update query and directly closes the window on Chrome. I am now calling javascript close method after I am done with the update.

```
sConn.Close
    Set objRecord = Nothing
    Set sConn = Nothing
    Response.Write("<script language=javascript>CancelWindow();</script>") // added this line
```